# Sort WooCommerce shipping options by ascending cost with free shipping at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I'm trying to sort woocommerce shipping options. I want to sort from lowest to highest price, but I need the free shipping options last.

I'm working from [WooCommerce: Sort Shipping Costs from Low to High](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-sort-shipping-costs-low-high/)

How do I put 0 last?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates' , 'businessbloomer_sort_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
   
function businessbloomer_sort_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    
    if ( empty( $rates ) ) return;
   
    if ( ! is_array( $rates ) ) return;
    
    uasort( $rates, function ( $a, $b ) { 
        if ( $a == $b ) return 0;
        return ( $a->cost < $b->cost ) ? -1 : 1; 
    } );
    
    return $rates;
   
    // NOTE: BEFORE TESTING EMPTY YOUR CART
       
}
```

Comment: Make it return 1 if a == 0 and b != 0, and -1 if a !=0 and b==0 …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will sort shipping options by cost from lower to higher with zero cost and empty cost last.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates' , 'sort_shipping_method_by_cost_zero_empty_cost_last', 10, 2 );
function sort_shipping_method_by_cost_zero_empty_cost_last( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( empty( $rates ) || ! is_array( $rates ) ) return;

    // Sort shipping methods based on cost
    uasort( $rates, function ( $a, $b ) {
        if ( $a == $b ) return 0;
        return ( $a->cost < $b->cost ) ? -1 : 1;
    } );

    $free = $zero = []; // Initializing

    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // For "free shipping" methods
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            // set them on a separated array
            $free[$rate_key] = $rate;

            // Remove "Free shipping" method from $rates array
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        } 
        // For other shipping rates with zero cost
        elseif ( $rate->cost == 0 ) {
            // set them on a separated array
            $zero[$rate_key] = $rate;

            // Remove the current method from $rates array
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }

    // Merge zero cost and "free shipping" methods at the end if they exist
    return ! empty( $free ) || ! empty( $zero ) ? array_merge($rates, $zero, $free) : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** 
> 1). This code is already saved on your function.php file. 
> 2). In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save. 
> **You are done** and you can test it.

---

Now the same thing ** with zero cost and empty cost first**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates' , 'sort_shipping_method_by_cost_empty_zero_cost_first', 10, 2 );
function sort_shipping_method_by_cost_empty_zero_cost_first( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( empty( $rates ) || ! is_array( $rates ) ) return;

    // Sort shipping methods based on cost
    uasort( $rates, function ( $a, $b ) {
        if ( $a == $b ) return 0;
        return ( $a->cost < $b->cost ) ? -1 : 1;
    } );

    $free = $zero = []; // Initializing

    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // For "free shipping" methods
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            // set them on a separated array
            $free[$rate_key] = $rate;

            // Remove "Free shipping" method from $rates array
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        } 
        // For other shipping rates with zero cost
        elseif ( $rate->cost == 0 ) {
            // set them on a separated array
            $zero[$rate_key] = $rate;

            // Remove the current method from $rates array
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }

    // Merge zero cost and "free shipping" methods at the end if they exist
    return ! empty( $free ) || ! empty( $zero ) ? array_merge($free, $zero, $rates) : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** 
> 1). This code is already saved on your function.php file. 
> 2). In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save. 
> **You are done** and you can test it.