# Sort WooCommerce shipping options by type and by ascending cost

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, shipping-method

Following [Sort WooCommerce shipping options by ascending cost with free shipping at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570577/sort-woocommerce-shipping-options-by-ascending-cost-with-free-shipping-at-the-en/62579857#62579857) answer thread, I have tried to sort all shipping options by type and by ascending cost:

- Free shipping options first,
- followed by Flat rate options,
- then Paid shipping options by ascending cost
- and last Local pickup option(s) as very few customers use it.

I haven't been able to make it work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, [based on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62579857/3730754), will sort shipping rates by type and by ascending cost:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates' , 'sort_shipping_method_by_type_and_by_asc_cost', 10, 2 );
function sort_shipping_method_by_type_and_by_asc_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( empty( $rates ) || ! is_array( $rates ) ) return;

    // Sort shipping methods based on cost
    uasort( $rates, function ( $a, $b ) {
        if ( $a == $b ) return 0;
        return ( $a->cost < $b->cost ) ? -1 : 1;
    } );

    $free = $flat = $local = $other = []; // Initializing

    // Loop through shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
        // For "Free shipping" methods
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free[$rate_key] = $rate;
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        } 
        // For "Flat rate"
        elseif ( 'flat_rate' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $flat[$rate_key] = $rate;
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
        // For "Local pickup"
        elseif ( 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $local[$rate_key] = $rate;
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        } 
        // Other shipping methods
        else {
            $other[$rate_key] = $rate;
            unset($rates[$rate_key]);
        }
    }
    // Merge separated rates
    return array_merge($free, $flat, $other, $local);
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

> **Inmportant:** You need to refresh shipping methods cache, by emptying your cart.