# Sort shipping methods displayed in WooCommerce Cart and Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, shipping-method

For WooCommerce, I create a shipping method using a plugin, and I'm trying to change the order using this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'mostrar_metodo_personalizado', 10, 2);
function mostrar_metodo_personalizado($rates, $package) {
    $nombre_del_metodo = 'Zona 1';

    if (isset($rates[$nombre_del_metodo])) {
        $rates[$nombre_del_metodo]->sort_order = 1;
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

But it's not working, can someone explained me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this can be done in your WooCommerce shipping settings. You can sort shipping methods by dragging the little icon [image] located on the left of each shipping method:

[image]

This should work on most cases.

---

##### You can do it also programmatically.

###### 1) Finding the correct shipping method keys

First, as you are not using **the right shipping methods key reference** to be used in the code, to find the right shipping methods key reference, use the following:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_test_output', 10);
function wp_footer_test_output() {
    if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
        echo '<pre>';
        foreach ( WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0')['rates'] as $rate ) {
            printf('For this <strong>"%s"</strong> shipping method, the key is: <code>%s</code><br>', $rate->label, $rate->id);
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Then in your website, add a product to cart and go to cart page. On the footer you will see displayed all your active shipping methods with their reference keys.

###### 2) Sorting displayed shipping methods

Once you get the correct Key for the desired shipping method, you can remove the code and use this shipping method key below.

The following code will move the desired displayed shipping method at first:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'sort_shipping_methods', 10, 2);
function sort_shipping_methods($rates, $package) {
    // Here define the correct shipping method key
    $shipping_method_key = 'flat_rate:9';

    if (isset($rates[$shipping_method_key])) {
        $rates1[$shipping_method_key] = $rates[$shipping_method_key];
        unset($rates[$shipping_method_key]);
    }
    return isset($rates1) ? array_merge($rates1, $rates) : $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping method cache.

Related threads:

- [Sort WooCommerce shipping options by ascending cost with free shipping at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570577/sort-woocommerce-shipping-options-by-ascending-cost-with-free-shipping-at-the-en/62579857#62579857)
- [Sort WooCommerce shipping options by type and by ascending cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876978/sort-woocommerce-shipping-options-by-type-and-by-ascending-cost/76877345#76877345)