# PHP Warning when Rearranging WooCommerce Shipping Methods in the Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, shipping-method

Can anyone tell me why I am getting a PHP warning for the below code?

The warning is triggered by this line:

```
foreach($available_shipping_methods as $carrier_id => $carrier){
```

The error message is: 
PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-child/functions.php on line 000

The code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'wf_sort_shipping_methods', 10, 2);

function wf_sort_shipping_methods($available_shipping_methods, $package)
{
    // Arrange shipping methods as per your requirement
    $sort_order = array(
        'wf_shipping_ups'           =>  array(),
        'flat_rate'                 =>  array(),
        'local_pickup'              =>  array(),
        'request_shipping_quote'    =>  array(),
                
    );
    
    // unsetting all methods that needs to be sorted
    foreach($available_shipping_methods as $carrier_id => $carrier){
        $carrier_name   =   current(explode(":",$carrier_id));
        if(array_key_exists($carrier_name,$sort_order)){
            $sort_order[$carrier_name][$carrier_id] =       $available_shipping_methods[$carrier_id];
            unset($available_shipping_methods[$carrier_id]);
        }
    }
    
    // adding methods again according to sort order array
    foreach($sort_order as $carriers){
        $available_shipping_methods =   array_merge($available_shipping_methods,$carriers);
    }
    return $available_shipping_methods;
}
```

Comment: what is the warning message?

Comment: You should first check if $available_shipping_methods is indeed an array and is not empty before iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't need any code to rearrange shipping methods as this can be done directly in the settings for each shipping Zone, see:

[Sort shipping methods displayed in WooCommerce Cart and Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019617/sort-shipping-methods-displayed-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout/77021056#77021056)

[image]

If you still need to sort shipping methods programmatically from an array of method IDs (slugs), use the following instead:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'reorganize_shipping_methods_from_method_id', 10, 2 );
function reorganize_shipping_methods_from_method_id( $rates, $package )
{
    // Here set the desired sorting by shipping method ID in the array
    $desired_sorting = array( 'wf_shipping_ups', 'flat_rate', 'local_pickup', 'request_shipping_quote' );
    $sorted_rates    = array(); // Initializing

     // Loop through desired shipping method sorting array
    foreach( $desired_sorting as $method_id ) {
        // Loop through shipping rates available for current shipping package
        foreach( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if( $rate->method_id === $method_id ) {
                $sorted_rates[$rate_key] = $rate;
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Merge both arrays (in case you didn't list all shipping methods IDs)
    return array_merge( $sorted_rates, $rates );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping method cache.

Other related threads:

- [Sort WooCommerce shipping options by ascending cost with free shipping at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570577/sort-woocommerce-shipping-options-by-ascending-cost-with-free-shipping-at-the-en/62579857#62579857)
- [Sort WooCommerce shipping options by type and by ascending cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876978/sort-woocommerce-shipping-options-by-type-and-by-ascending-cost/76877345#76877345)